# Attempting to run Powershell on Remote Computer - Errors

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am wanting to access another windows device on my local network and run powershell commands.  In my mind, it would be similar to SSH into a linux box.  I would have an open window on my machine, but would be operating within the remote machine so that I can execute composer install or php artisan migrate type commands on the remote machine.

I have followed the instructions from:
https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

I am attempting to use

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <RemoteComputerName> -Credential <RemoteUser>
```

When I run the command, I get a popup with the username populated and asking for a password.  I have entered my MS password for the account.  (I have changed the password from within Windows to ensure they are synced)

And I get the following error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server <REMOTECOMPUTER> failed with the following error message : The WinRM client
cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not
joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not
be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For
more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <REMOTECOMPUTER> -Credential <USER>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (<REMOTECOMPUTER>:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  And, maybe more importantly, is there a better way/utility to accomplish my goal?  The remote computer is hosting WAMP and I just want to be execute development commands remotely so I can move the RemoteComputer into the basement and not have to spin my chair around to type on it.

TIA

Comment: There's a lot of information in that error message but you haven't said why you did with it. Have you considered Remote Desktop?

Comment: I've considered remote desktop (as well as various screen share utilities) and that may end up being the best approach.  But, in my mind, it was going to be easier to just open PowerShell - connect to the RemotePowershell, and execute commands without going through all the hoops of connecting to a remote desktop, opening powershell, and then typing.  In other words, I don't really need all the graphical benefit of a remote desktop.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but there's a conceptual [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Troubleshooting) help topic.

Comment: Have you set up TrustedHosts properly on *both* machines?

Comment: You will need to set up WinRM. There are plenty of explanations on how to do that on the internet.

Comment: I've activated WinRM - I've added the opposite machine to both machines as a trusted host.  I've reset the server admin password.  I can't seem to get them to connect. =/